# Modeling a database (ERD) that has quirky behavior

Tags: entity-relationship, erd, database-design

One of the databases that I'm working on has some quirky behavior that I want to account for in the entity-relationship diagram.

One of the behaviors is that there is a 'booking' table and a 'invoice' table. When a 'booking' is invoiced, then the record is inserted into the 'invoice' table and then deleted from the 'booking' table.

However, a reference is still kept of the booking number.

How do we model this? Big arrow between the tables and some text beside it describing what happens?

***No, changing the database schema is not possible at this point in time***

*Edit*: This is the type of diagram that I want to use:
[alt text http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/5601/erdartistperformssong.png](http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/5601/erdartistperformssong.png)
[Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ERD-artist-performs-song.svg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by ERD, you mean the original "Chen" diagrams where the relationship was words written in a diamond, then you have a relationship between between Booking and Invoice.  It's a special kind of relationship that's NOT implemented with a simple foreign key; it's implemented via a complicated move and a constraint.

If, by ERD, you mean the diagrams that ERwin draws, then you don't have an easy way to do this.  It tends to focus you on drawing PK-FK relationships.  You have a non-PK-FK relationship between these things.  Some kind of line with text is about all you can do.

Arrows, BTW, aren't appropriate because the ERD shows the "state" of the database.  Data flowing around isn't part of an ERD.  You do have a relationship, it's just not a typical PK-FK relationship.  It's an atypical relationship based on rows existing in some places and not existing in others.

In the UML you can easily draw this as a "constraint" among the relationships.

Comment: @S.Lott "Data flowing around isn't part of an ERD." totally what I was trying to say but said much better.

Comment: @Lott.  You have heard of IDEF1X, haven't you.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: What does IDEF1X have to do with this kind of dynamic state change?

Comment: @Lott.  It is not a "dynamic state change" any more than the normal online concurrent changes to any active database, perfectly ordinary.  Maybe you cannot show it in a DM, but that does not make it something "abnormal". IDEF1X: read my answer.  You are quoting ERwin, but you do not appear to know what/why it does what it does. And what you say about ERwin (implying IDEF1X), and about "non-PK-FK relationship" for Nitrodist,  is simply incorrect.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: "When a 'booking' is invoiced, then the record is inserted into the 'invoice' table and then deleted from the 'booking' table"  This isn't dynamic?  Why did you introduce the term "normal" and "abnormal"?  I'm saying that there's no *easy* visual model for this.   What did you think I was saying?

Comment: @Lott: Understood all that.  Inserting and deleting rows is normal in a normal database.  There are tousands of apps that delete from one table and insert into another.  Look up queue and message tables.  But that is not the point, it is that you did not know it could be drawn; or placed in a Relational database; you incorrectly stated it was "non-PK-FK relationship".

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: There's no easy to to describe a dynamic relationship.  In this case,  it's one PK-FK that is replaced by another.  I have no idea what words do use for this.  You can (1) complain or (2) suggest an improvement.  I like the complaining because I relish negativity.  Nothing is more helpful than simply saying "You're wrong" without providing any alternative.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: "it is that you did not know it could be drawn; or placed in a Relational database"  False and false.  I suggested that UML would be a better diagram and it can clearly be placed in a relational database.  At no time did I dispute that.  I'm saying that there's no easy visual model for this.  Why do you keep saying other things?

Comment: @Lott: stick to the technical matter. *In this case, it's one PK-FK that is replaced by another* is false: both FKs are implemented in DDL and not changed.  One **row** is deleted and another **row** is added, the **word** for this is *normal online activity in a database*.  There is no "alternative", I was pointing out the misinformation you posted. *no easy visual model for this*: have you found my model ?  Have you found the standard IDEF1X notation for this normal easy visual representation of a subtype (that you had never seen before & therefore did not exist *for you*) ?

Comment: @Lott.  The bottom line is, you posted incorrect information, and misinformation, about something that you had not seen before.  At SO, the guidelines encourage us to correct misinformation, that's all I was doing.  Now if you admitted your mistake and corrected it, it would be simple.  Very sad to see that you make make a simple thing so complex by obfuscating it.

Comment: "When a 'booking' is invoiced, then the record is inserted into the 'invoice' table and then deleted from the 'booking' table" and "In this case, it's one PK-FK that is replaced by another is false".  Confuse me.  The question says one is replaced by another.  It sure sounds clear to me.  And you're saying that the question is wrong?  Interesting approach to clearing up a problem.  Both PK-FK relationships are *possible* but they're exclusive *through time*.  The temporal change is hard to annotate.  Yes, updates happen.  But relationships that are exclusive *through time* don't have notation.

Comment: @Lott. Evidently you cannot tell the difference between the Data Model (definitions) and the activity, the population in the database.  You are still making a simple thing, easily expressed in a DM, easily defined in DDL, very complex.  Nothing "temporal" about it.  No Relations are "weplaced". Inserts and deletes do not need special symbols.  Evidently working with this database-modelling subject is very challenging, very confusing, for you.  Best to learn the subject, try and understand the professionals, instead of posting incorrect "answers".

Comment: @PerformanceDBA.  Okay.  You're simply claiming that even though there's no notation, it's okay.  I'm claiming **the same thing**.  There's no notation.  And it's okay.  But, there's no notation in an ERD.  I can't make it any plainer.  It's **okay** to do updates.  It's **okay**.  I still agree that updates are **okay**.  I always agreed that updates are **okay**.  My point is this.  There's no way to draw it on a picture.  No way.  To draw.  Updates.  On A Picture.  Updates are **okay**.

Comment: @Lott. Are you sure you have IT experience? Stop paraphrasing me, you keep getting it wrong, just read my words. Anyone reading these comments can see your dishonesty, your ducking and weaving, for themselves, you can stop anytime you like. *If, by ERD, you mean the diagrams that ERwin draws, then you don't have an easy way to do this. It tends to focus you on drawing PK-FK relationships. You have a non-PK-FK relationship between these things. Some kind of line with text is about all you can do.* **False: It is a PK::FK relation. False: There is a symbol.**

Comment: **False:** you can do more than text if you have seen the symbols. First you posted that delete/inserts were *dynamic state change* now, even you are saying **False:** it is normal.  *One PK::FK relation is* revoked *and another relation* replaces *it* **False:** both remain true (the tables have more than one row). *Temporal change, Exclusive through time* **Dishonesty & Obfuscation** *There is no notation* **False:** There is a notation, but you can't see it. *You're claiming the same thing* **False:** you are trying to get some credibility by sounding like me.  **Sad, really.**

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: "dynamic state change now, even you are saying False: it is normal".  I thought you said dynamic state change (i.e., Update) is normal.  I thought I agreed.  Sorry for agreeing with you.  "Temporal change, Exclusive through time Dishonesty & Obfuscation There is no notation False: There is a notation, but you can't see it.".  Please share this notation.  Please.  Please include it in an answer.  Please.  Claiming I'm wrong is unhelpful.  Posting the right answer is helpful.

Comment: @Lott.  The words are still up there, read again from the first comment.  Symbol: OMG. Same as last week, remember ? Read. my. Answer. Follow. the. Bold. Dark. blue. links. Find. the. diagram; Read. the. document; look. for. the. Subtype-Exclusive. symbol. described. in. the. Answer. Is. that. s.l.o.w. e.n.o.u.g.h ?  Maybe. next. week. you. will. connect. the. dots.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what these people are talking about.

1. The Entity Relation Diagram doesn't describe the data fully; yes of course, it only shows Entities and Relations, it doesn't show Attributes. That's why it is called an ERD and not a Data Model.  Evidently many people here can't tell the difference.
2. The Data Model is supposed to show as much as possible.  But it depends on (a) the standard [if any] that you use and (b) the Notation.  Some show more than others.  IDEF1X which is the only Relational modelling Standard (NIST 184 of 1993). It is the most complete, and shows intricacies and complexities that other notations do not show.  Recently MS and others have come out with "simplified" notations, of course, much is lost in the "ERDs".
3. It is not "process flow", it is a relation in a database.
4. UML is completely inappropriate for modelling data, especially when there is at least one Standard plus several non-standard but commonly used data modelling notations.  There is nothing that can be shown in UML that can't be shown in IDEF1X.  But most developers here have never heard of it (developers should not be modelling unless they have acquired modelling skills, but that is another story)..
5. This is a perfectly legal; it may not be commonly known, but it is legal and named.  It is a **Supertype-Subtype** relation, except that the Cardinality is 1::0-n instead of 1::0-1.  The IDEF1X Notation (right) has a Subtype symbol.  Note there is only one relation at the parent end; and one each at the child end.  And of course the crows feet show the cardinality.  These relations can be **Exclusive** or **Non-exclusive**; yours is Exclusive; that is what the X through the half-circle means.

   - ERwin is the only modelling (not diagramming) tool that implements IDEF1X, and thus has the full complement of the IDEF1X Notation.
   - Of course, the Standard, the modelling capability, are all in the mind, not in the tool.  I draw Data Models that are IDEF1X-compliant using a simple drawing tool.
6. I find that some developers baulk at the Subtype symbol, so I show a simplified version (left) in my IDEF1X models; it is intended to convey the sense of exclusivity, while the retention of the single line at the parent end indicates it is a subtype.

**Lott: Click here**▶[**Link to Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Nitrodist%20DM.pdf)◀**Lott: Click here**

[**Link to IDEF1X Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) for those who are unfamiliar with the Relational Modelling Standard.

Comment: Could you provide an example diagram that shows the relationship?  That would be more useful than most of the words in this answer.

Comment: @Lott: See the link **Data Model** ? Click on it.  If you have trouble understanding the notation, click on the **IDEF1X Notation** link.  I checked the links when I posted, and they work from my browser.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA:  You can embed graphics in your answer.  That's helpful.  You can complain that someone didn't click every single link in every single answer.  I like the complaining.  It's better than embedding the graphics where everyone can see them.  I like the negativity of refusing to pander to people.  I like standing up for your right to make things obscure and blame other for failing to perceive the obscurity.  Helpful.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @Lott: Er, that was you doing the complaining.  You had that whole fantasy all on your own.  There is no end to the waffling of the challenged, is there ?

Comment: @PerformanceDBA: Please include the graphics in your answer.  Please.

Comment: @Lott. You are going around in circles, all on your own. Please read comment 1, then 2. Please read the Answer first, otherwise you might forget what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a process flow, not an entity relationship.  If at the time the entry is added to invoice, and the entry is deleted from booking, then there is never a relationship between the two.  There is never a situation where you can traverse that relationship because there is never a record in both places that can be related together.

ERD don't describe the database fully.  There are other things like process flow and use cases that detail other facets of the system.

This is kind of an analogy to UML for software.  A class diagram doesn't show you all the different ways classes interact.  One class might initialize locally and call functions of another class, but because there is not composition or inheritance that relates those two classes, then the class diagram doesn't show this relationship.  Only when you fully document the system with all the various types of diagrams can you see all the facets of how it operates.